# Insert into select BigQuery nested columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert data to a table with `SELECT` clause. 
the query - 
`` INSERT INTO ds.table (entity, `user.id`) SELECT user.id FROM ds.table2 `` 
the columns to which I want to insert are nested columns, but the query fails on

> Column user.id is not present in table ds.table

and the column is present

Answer (score 0):

The user.id column is in the ds.table2, but are you sure that it has the same name in ds.table? I ask this because I cannot see the data and the error says that there is no column named user.id in the ds.table. It would be clarifying if you could add a small table as a description of the data.

Also, you are inserting two columns but selecting only one. The query should be something like the following in case it exists the column user.id in the ds.table:

```
    INSERT INTO ds.table (user.id) 
    SELECT user.id 
    FROM ds.table2
```